# php end tag in strings breaks vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, php, syntax-highlighting

I have the following line a long PHP file: `preg_match_all("/<.*?>/", $rows[2],$tmp);` and after the `?>` in this line the syntax highlighting in vim is gone for the rest of the file. How can I fix that?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with Vim, but my work around has always been to break up the end tag in the string: preg_match_all("/<.*?" . ">/", $rows[2],$tmp);

Comment: For me the highlighting is correct, it must have been fixed. Is it ok now for you?